# Transfer funds from one personal account to another directly with PayPal API in PHP

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-adaptive-payments

I want to know what is the best choice to transfer the funds from one personal to another in PHP.
There was some solutions before, but now those are deprecated such as Adaptive API etc.
I found one solution in [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/pay-another-account/), but when I transfer the funds, it sent to my default business account.
Here is the code:

```
$params = [
    'intent' => 'CAPTURE',
    'purchase_units' => [
        [
            'amount' => [
                'currency_code' => $currency,
                'value' => (string) $amount
            ],
            'payee' => [
                'email_address' => $address //receiver user PayPal email address
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
$data = $this->encodeData($params);
$headers = $this->getAuthHeaders($data);
$res = $this->execute('POST, '/v2/checkout/orders', $data, $headers);
```

It's really strange why I can't send it directly to this recipient.

Comment: Hmm, that actually looks correct at first blush. Can you runtime log dump your `$data` and `$res` right after they're set, so we can see where things may be going wrong?

Comment: {"id":"1U6354702F236135S","status":"CREATED","links":[{"href":"https:\/\/api.sandbox.paypal.com\/v2\/checkout\/orders\/1U6354702F236135S","rel":"self","method":"GET"},{"href":"https:\/\/www.sandbox.paypal.com\/checkoutnow?token=1U6354702F236135S","rel":"approve","method":"GET"},{"href":"https:\/\/api.sandbox.paypal.com\/v2\/checkout\/orders\/1U6354702F236135S","rel":"update","method":"PATCH"},{"href":"https:\/\/api.sandbox.paypal.com\/v2\/checkout\/orders\/1U6354702F236135S\/capture","rel":"capture","method":"POST"}]}  : Here is the `$res`

Comment: DATA====>{"intent":"CAPTURE","purchase_units":[{"amount":{"currency_code":"USD","value":"50"},"payee":{"email":"sb-13431550910@personal.example.com"}}],"application_context":{"user_action":"PAY_NOW","shipping_preference":"NO_SHIPPING","return_url":"https:\/\/xxx.com","cancel_url":"https:\/\/xxx.com"}} : Here is $data

Comment: but after approve it `payee` address changed with my main credential owner account:

{..."status":"APPROVED","purchase_units":[{"reference_id":"default","amount":{"currency_code":"USD","value":"50.00"},"payee":{"email_address":"htag@bodproductions.com"...],"payer":{"name":{"given_name":"John","surname":"Doe"},"email_address":"sb-ksyxz5947819@personal.example.com","payer_id":"96Z48PGVR3WRE","address":{"country_code":"US"}}....]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> DATA====>{"intent":"CAPTURE","purchase_units":[{"amount":{"currency_code":"USD","value":"50"},"payee":{"email":"sb-13431550910@personal.example.com"}}],"application_context":{"user_action":"PAY_NOW","shipping_preference":"NO_SHIPPING","return_url":"https://xxx.com","cancel_url":"https://xxx.com"}} : Here is $data

Your request data is specifying `email` rather than `email_address`, so this is unrecognized and ignored.

Check your encodeData function to see why this is happening.

Comment: After completed transaction, if I check the status again with capture api, it will be give error?
{"name":"INVALID_RESOURCE_ID","message":"The requested resource ID was not found","debug_id":"ffbbcd8fe8042","information_link":"https:\/\/developer.paypal.com\/docs\/api\/payments.payouts-batch\/#errors","details":[],"links":[]}

Comment: v1/payments/payouts is not related to any of the above, perhaps you are looking for v2/payments/captures, https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v2/#captures_get

Comment: However, since the receiver account is different than yours, you may not have permission to get by transaction ID.